# Pass function and useStates from another component as props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello everybody I am currently building a UI for food Delivery and all the dummy data,states and functions are in Home component and I want to pass the useStates and Function to Category Function to filter the dummy data by category.

*//The Home Component*

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState(categoryData)
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null)
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState(restaurantData)
const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState(initialCurrentLocation)

function onSelectedCategory(Category){
    let restaurantList = restaurantData.filter(a => a.categories.includes
    (category.id))
    
    setRestaurants(restaurantList)
    setSelectedCategory(category)
}



return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Top name={currentLocation.streetName}/>
        <Categories
            category={categories}
            funct={this.onSelectedCategory(Category)}
            />
    </SafeAreaView>
)
```

//The Category Component

```
const Categories = (props) => {
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={style.itemContainer}
            onPress={props.funct}
        >
            <View style={style.imgcontainer}>
            <Image
                source={item.icon}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={style.img}
                />
            </View>
            <Text style={style.namecontainer}>
                {item.name}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}


return (
    <View style={style.container}>
        <Text style={{...FONTS.h1}}>Main</Text>
        <Text style={{...FONTS.h1}}>Categories</Text>

        <FlatList
            data={props.category}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical:SIZES.padding * 2 }}
        />
    </View>
)
```

}

Comment: pass your function as reference: <Categories
            category={categories}
            funct={onSelectedCategory}
            />

Comment: then, call it inside item component: <TouchableOpacity style={style.itemContainer}
            onPress={()=>props.funct(item)}
        >

Comment: @tuannguyen thanks, but how can i call the selectedCategory in my Category Component?

Comment: you can pass selectedCategory as props to Category component like when you pass "categories"

Answer (score 0):

1. When you are passing the categories from Home component you're calling the prop category, but when you're trying to access it in your Category component, I see you only referring to item prop.
2. Be careful with naming convention it's importing as your project grows, try to name variables and eventListeners or functions. [react, handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `ContextAPI` and add the needed values and functions

1.Create a Context

```
export const HomeComponentContext = createContext();
```

2.In your `Home Component` Import the `HomeComponentContext`

```
<HomeComponentContext.Provider value={{categories,setCategories,...all other states or values}}>
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Top name={currentLocation.streetName}/>
        <Categories/>
    </SafeAreaView>
</HomeComponentContext.Provider>
```

3.In your `Categories Component` import `useContext` and `HomeComponentContext`

```
import { useContext } from 'react';

const { categories,setCategories,...all other states or values } =
    useContext(CoursePageContext);
```